# Center ok and cancel button with GridLayout

Tags: java, layout, swt

I built my own find dialog with some components to configure the search and I want to lay out the controls using the GridLayout.
But I'm not able to place the ok and cancel button. I want to center these buttons so the margin between the left edge of the window and the ok button, the margin between the ok and the cancel button as well as the margin between the cancel button and the right edge of the window is the same.

This is my current code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
    gridLayout.marginHeight = 10;
    gridLayout.marginWidth = 10;
    gridLayout.numColumns = 5;
    gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
    shell.setText("Find");

    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 5;
    Label label1 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label1.setLayoutData(gridData);
    label1.setText("Please enter the find text in the field below:");

    gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 5;
    Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
    text1.setLayoutData(gridData);

    gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 5;
    Button check1 = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
    check1.setLayoutData(gridData);
    check1.setText("Match case sensitivity");

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Button okButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    okButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    okButton.setText("&OK");
    shell.setDefaultButton(okButton);

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Button cancelButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    cancelButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    cancelButton.setText("&Cancel");

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

My problem is that the cancel button seems to be centered but the ok button is still aligned on the left.
What I want is a placement like for example: left edge, 50 pixels, ok button, 50 pixels, cancel button, 50 pixels, right edge.

It should look like this:

[image]

+++ EDITED +++

Ok, I found a solution. It's not perfect but it corresponds to my requirements in a satisfactorily way:

I'm now using two composites - one for the "main" controls and one for the buttons.
I sat a GridLayout with one cloumn to the window to place the composites among each other.
The button composite got also a GridLayout but with two columns for ok and cancel. And then I was able to center the buttons in the window with the GridData object.
My only problem is the horizontalSpacing between the buttons. I had to set it to an absolute value but it would be better to have a dynamic value (maybe depending on the whole width of the window). But I had no idea to realize this yet.
Here's what I built:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("Find");

    Composite mainComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    mainComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    mainComp.setLayoutData(new GridData());

    Label label1 = new Label(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
    label1.setLayoutData(new GridData());
    label1.setText("Please enter the find text in the field below:");

    Text text1 = new Text(mainComp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
    text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

    Button check1 = new Button(mainComp, SWT.CHECK);
    check1.setLayoutData(new GridData());
    check1.setText("Match case sensitivity");

    Composite buttonComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout buttonCompLayout = new GridLayout();
    buttonCompLayout.horizontalSpacing = 50;
    buttonCompLayout.numColumns = 2;
    buttonComp.setLayout(buttonCompLayout);
    buttonComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER));

    Button okButton = new Button(buttonComp, SWT.PUSH);
    okButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    okButton.setText("&OK");
    shell.setDefaultButton(okButton);

    Button cancelButton = new Button(buttonComp, SWT.PUSH);
    cancelButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    cancelButton.setText("&Cancel");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to base the spacing on the width of the window, you can listen to `SWT.Resize` and then update the `GridLayout#horizontalSpacing`. Afterwards, call `layout()` on the parent.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    layout.horizontalSpacing = 50;

    comp.setLayout(layout);
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.TOP, true, false));

    Button first = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    first.setText("First");
    first.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

    Button second = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
    second.setText("Second");
    second.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            int width = shell.getSize().x;
            layout.horizontalSpacing = (int) Math.round(0.1 * width);
            shell.layout(true, true);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    shell.forceFocus();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Your idea is very cool but now I've the problem of some curious effects: The window is suddenly double-sized (380 pixels instead of 190 before) and my text field is 400 pixels (wider than the window itself) and overlaps the right edge of the window. I don't know what GridLayout calculates here...

Comment: @altralaser I don't know either without seing your final code.

Comment: @altralaser Updated my answer. It doesn't rely on the `Label`s anymore.

Comment: First, thanks your help! Unfortunately the result of your code is the same like in my first example. The only difference is now the wider margin on left and right. But the buttons are not centered udner the text field or checkbox and with no "good" margin between ok and cancel. May I ask you what you are using to place ok and cancel buttons in your dialogs? Is there maybe something like a kind of inofficial standard?

Comment: @altralaser Please post an image that shows what you want it to look like, because I don't think I understand what you want.

Comment: I know - sometimes it's a bit complicated to describe layouts. I inserted a screenshot so you can see what I want to do. Please note that I used absolute values and setBounds to build this dialog and now I want to rebuild it with a layout manager. I prefer GridLayout but it can also be another one. Important for me is only that I can get the same look of the dialog window.

Comment: @altralaser I don't see how my answer differs from what you'd like to see. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In your answer you only make the marginLeft and marginRight wider. But you don't change the position of the buttons. The ok button is still aligned to the left what means that the left edge of the button is directly under the left edge of f.e. the checkbox. Or in other words: The ok button has the same margin from the left edge of the window like all other controls. But in my screenshot you can see that both buttons (ok and cancel) are centered in the window.

Comment: @altralaser no, I don't see that at all. My buttons are centered. I guess we just have to agree that I don't understand what you want.

Comment: In your example the text field is f.e. 50 pixels from the left edge of the window positioned and also the ok button. Both controls are placed directly on the left side. Your buttons can't be centered because you never use a center align. So your code would not lead to the same window layout.

Comment: @altralaser So what is it you want? The buttons centered but 50px apart? Should the buttons have the same width?

Comment: No, the width of the buttons is quite ok. What I'm now looking for is a idea to make the horizontalSpacing of buttonCompLayout dynamic depending on the window width. Let's say I've a dialog with width=300 then I want to set buttonCompLayout.horizontalSpacing to 50 but if I've a dialog with width=500 I want to set horizontalSpacing to f.e. 80. Or in other words: The spacing between the buttons should be small in small dialogs and larger in larger dialogs.

Comment: @altralaser Yeah, but the question is how big/small in relation to the other elements.

Comment: Hm, but the width of ok and cancel button is the same in every window so I thought it's only necessary to bind the horizontalSpacing to the window width?

Comment: @altralaser sure, that's possible, but bind it how?

Comment: @altralaser You've just said you want the spacing to be based on the width, but without knowing what you're looking for, I can't answer your question. It could be 10% of the width, 11%, 12%, ...